# Google Terms of use always need accept: "accept all" or "reject all"

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, google-image-search

When I normally start the chrome browser, I don't have to accept anything anymore, it works right away.
But using chromedriver (python, selenium) I have to accept conditions every time.

I don't use incognito mode.
In the settings, I set the acceptance of cookies.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

chromeDriverPath=r'C:\Users\Aorus\Downloads\Z_ARCHIWUM\PythonScript\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://google.com')
```

Is there any line of code that I can accept automatically? Or maybe something else needs to be changed in the browser settings?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCAfQ.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can click it like you would click any other element on the page. Since it is an element with a dynamic id you could locate it by text. Something like this as locator:

```
xpath=//button/div[contains(text(),'Accept all')]
```